# C#. How can I use a method described in a base class with the arguments of inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Lets imagine the following structure of classes:

```cs
    class A{
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public A(double x, double y){
            X=x; Y=y;
        };   
        public A MiddlePoint(A[] a){
            A resultPnt = new A(0,0);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
                resultPnt.X += a[i].X;
                resultPnt.Y += a[i].Y;
            }
            resultPnt.X = (this.X + resultPnt.X)/(a.Length + 1);
            resultPnt.Y = (this.Y + resultPnt.Y)/(a.Length + 1);
        }
    }

    class B:A{}
```

Is it safety to use method like this :

```cs
B b = new B();
B[] arr = new B[2];
b.MiddlePoint(arr);
```

?
If not, what should I do to make this method call safety except overloading it in the class B? It is not convenient every time overload this method in every inherited class.

P.S. Safety means without throwing exception in any case.

Comment: Define "safety" in this instance...

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: This  is how Inheritance is supposed to work...

Comment: Your definition of B is wrong, it should not compile - A has no parameterless constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code should work in C#.  (At least, something like it compiles on my machine under C# 4.0, once you add a no-arg constructor to `A`.).

Your code as written will return an instance of `A` when passed in an array of any subtype of `A`.  If you insist on, for example, getting back an instance of `B` instead when you pass in an array of `B`, you could use generics, similar to the following:

```
class A{
    public double X;
    public double Y;

    public A(double x, double y){
        X=x; Y=y;
    }
    public A(){
        // needs to have a no-arg constructor to satisfy new() constraint on MiddlePoint
    }
    public T MiddlePoint<T>(T[] a) where T : A, new() {
        T resultPnt = new T();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
            resultPnt.X += a[i].X;
            resultPnt.Y += a[i].Y;
        }
        resultPnt.X = (this.X + resultPnt.X)/(a.Length + 1);
        resultPnt.Y = (this.Y + resultPnt.Y)/(a.Length + 1);
    }
}

class B:A{}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! It is a good idea! I absolutely forgot about the generics :-).

Answer (score 1):

It's like you create a new array of type of `A`, and every instance of `B` in your array uppercast to `A` and insert in that array. After pass that array of `A` type objects to the method.

So this is as it intended to work.

More on this you can find on: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee207183.aspx)